# Docker build cannot install python requirements from file if python project is mounted in docker-compose

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, requirements.txt

I have a python image I run from `docker-compose.yml`. I mount the python code as a volume so I do not need to rebuild the container with every code change:

##### docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  python:
    container_name: py
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./app:/usr/src/app
    env_file:
      - .env
    working_dir: /usr/src/app
    command: python ./core/main.py
```

Where `build: .` is refering to the `Dockerfile` in the same directory.

The `app/` which is the python root directory, contains standard `requirements.txt`. The problem is I cannot install the dependencies in `requirements.txt` during docker build using `RUN pip install -r requirements.txt` in `Dockerfile` since the volume is not yet mounted.

I can't seem to solve this which makes me think I am not practicing the best usage of docker/docker-compose.

How can I solve this?

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7.12-slim-bullseye
RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED 1
```

As expeceted, running `docker compose build py` causes:

```
ERROR: Could not open requirements file: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'requirements.txt'
```

Comment: Show us your `Dockerfile`!

Comment: @KlausD. updated question with `Dockerfile`

Comment: You need to have the `pip install` in an `ENTRYPOINT`.

Comment: A Python virtual environment, without Docker, might make a better day-to-day development environment.  If you're trying to run an unmodified `python` image with host code, Docker is just adding an isolation layer you don't want in the middle of the stack.

Comment: You will have to `COPY` the `requirements.txt` into the image before using it. Actually you are not copying anything into the image.

Comment: To clarify: There are three options to use Docker here. 1) Use a blank Python image and do everything in a container with a volume mounted. 2) Build an image with everything inside to just run your code. This is usually done in deployments. 3) Copy the `requirements.txt` into the image and install the dependencies while building. Then run a container mounting your code as a volume. If the requirements change you have to rebuild the image.

Answer (score 0):

instead of doing this on docker-compose:

```
volumes:
      - ./app:/usr/src/app
```

I usually use this other approach in Dockerfile:

```
WORKDIR /usr/src/app #if folder doesn't exist this will be created, so you can omit RUN mkdir /usr/src/app
COPY ./app/requirements.txt /usr/src/app
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY ./app /usr/src/app
```

if you are using a virtual folder inside  you will need a .dockerignore file to avoid that space consumption in the container